# Find the most and least values of 8 calculated fields

Tags: dashboard, tableau-desktop

I have 8 calculated fields in Tableau and I need to find the lowest 2 of them and highest value. How do I do that? is that possible in Tableau?

Comment: if you can place all the measures in a page, I think you can filter them accordingly

Comment: @MKD I don't want to filter I want to find the min and max out of the 8

Comment: you can define min() & max() in the filter options itself

Comment: but that would be defined on 1 measure I want the min and the max on all of them

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two functions named MIN() -- the same applies to MAX(), but I'll just talk about MIN().

The most commonly used takes a single argument - and is an aggregate function, such as MIN([Sales]). It operates on multiple records and returns the minimum value found in the whole set of records. It is translated into the SQL MIN() function for relational data sources.

The other version of MIN() takes two arguments, such as MIN([x], [y]). It is a record level function and operates on a single record and returns the minimum value of its two arguments for that record.  It is translated into the SQL LEAST() function for relational data sources.

You want to use the second form. Unfortunately, Tableau restricts it to two arguments, but you can simply nest multiple calls as in MIN(MIN(a, b), c)